# What is the difference between 'test/' and 'test/**' in a '.gitignore'?

Tags: git, gitignore

According to the [.gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) `test/` would ignore the test directory and everything in it. Additionally, `test/**` is described as `matches everything inside`.

I have been experimenting and cannot figure out what the difference between these two is. Can anyone provide an example where those behave differently?

Comment: This has been closed wrongly. In the question "What's the difference between Git ignoring directory and directory/*?" there is no mention of directory/** !

And I am interested by an answer to the original question ... although I suspect the answer is: there's no difference, it's just 2 different syntax producing the same result.